# Detect if Windows Store app is running in assigned access (kiosk mode)

Tags: windows-8, kiosk-mode

I know there is no official way to detect if my Windows Store app is running in assigned access (kiosk mode), but can you suggest a workaround? Perhaps a function that fails in kiosk mode? Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Try `Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(...)` or `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync (...)`, it may return `false` if app is in assigned access.

Comment: Did not work, as launching a file or URI when the user is not in kiosk would actually end up launching and this is not desired.

Comment: Ended up using a special name for the kiosk user and checking on user name.